# Toggle a CSS class on clicked element in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use the predefined AngularJS Directives to toggle a class on click without having to write JavaScript code.

I tried to toggle class by using `ng-class`:

```
<button ng-model="toggle" ng-class="{'red' : toggle}">Change Class</button>
```

<kbd>[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwQJWL)</kbd>

Comment: that's not how `ng-model` works.  buttons aren't attached to data.  Instead, you should remove `ng-model` entirely and use `ng-click` to change the state of the data, like the answer provided by @Tushar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a switch with ternary operator as follow

```
<button ng-model="toggle" ng-class="toggle ? 'red' : ''" ng-click="toggle=!toggle">Change Class</button>
```

1. `ng-click="toggle=!toggle"`: When clicked on button the value of `toggle` will be reversed and updated in the same variable.
2. The ternary operation in `ng-class` will check if the `toggle` is truthy, then add class `red` else it removes the class.

**Demo:**

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <button ng-model="toggle" ng-class="toggle ? 'red' : ''" ng-click="toggle=!toggle">Change Class</button>
</div>
```

---

You can also use

```
<button ng-model="toggle" ng-class="{'red' : toggle}" ng-click="toggle=!toggle">Change Class</button>
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <button ng-model="toggle" ng-class="{'red': toggle}" ng-click="toggle=!toggle">Change Class</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but I have an `ng-click="function()"` with a function. Can I use two ng-clicks, one for the function and another for `ng-click="toggle=!toggle"`?

Comment: @Fuiba You can add the toggling in the function itself. No need of two `ng-click`s.

Comment: @Fuiba - inside ng-click is just javascript, so if you are not allowed to touch the js files, you can still call the function e.g.  ng-click="toggle=!toggle; myFunction()"